# Suspicious hyperlinks (all hex URLs) in e-mail

Tags: email, url, social-engineering

I'm communicating with a job headhunter over LinkedIn and he sent me an e-mail containing information about a position.  However, I noticed that all of the hyperlinks in the e-mail (even the one on his e-mail address) had very strange URLs.  They all had the same format.  Here's an example (with some details obfuscated):

> https://23b7eec.com/ffoollllooww/track433085381116499/my.email@email.com/mailto%253his.email@email.com

Running curl on the domain names showed

```
<html> <head> <meta name="google-site-verification" content="Vv4vPR01zdF-4Q2UVUnWGUXU49anphh0Y8QjscT01TU" /> <title> My title </title> </head> <body> Go to <a href="http://www.rightinbox.com">RightInbox.com</a> </body> </html>
```

Is this safe to click on?

Comment: If you know the email of the other person, why do you need to click any links? Why don't you just write an email?

Comment: He's included links to other sites.

Comment: Why do he needs other sites?

Comment: Because he’s finding me open positions and is linking to the relevant companies.

Comment: Did you change the domain name? Because `23b7eec.com` does not seem to be a registered domain.

Comment: It can be kind of referral system, so that a click registers you as a success referral case for your headhunter. This can also be just a usual self registration for spam. Solid headhunters do neither.

Comment: You say "all hex" but your example doesn't have hex. Is the hex relevant?

Comment: @schroeder I assumed that they meant the domain name (`23b7eec` contains only/all hexadecimal characters).

Comment: @tim well it brings up more questions. Is the domain name all hex characters, is the entire URL hex? Is it hex characters with a ".com"? Each will have a different concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it looks off is that it's a tracking link (as indicated by `/track`).

This is not entirely uncommon. You can sometimes see it in marketing emails, where every link is automatically rewritten to point to some tracking server (which tracks the opening of the link and then redirects to the real target).

Just based on these being tracking links, we can't answer if it's safe to click on or not. In addition to any other link you receive via email - which could be safe or unsafe - there are a couple additional things to consider:

- your click will be tracked. Tracked info will likely include: when you clicked the link, which link you clicked, the email the link was in, your PII (from the looks of it at least your email address), probably your IP, etc.
- the target of the link is obfuscated. So you can't hover over it to see the target domain to decide if you want to click on it or not.

So you should take the usual precautions when clicking on an unknown link from a semi-trusted (I assume) source:

- if you are worried about drive-by-download issue (malware, browser exploits etc), don't click the link. Or at least use a dedicated VM or similar.
- if you are worried about downloaded files (viruses, etc), don't download anything (esp. no malicious files; executables, doc/docm and other macro formats, etc). Or at least use a dedicated VM or similar.
- if you are worried about client-side attacks (XSS, CORS, CSRF, etc), open the links in a dedicated browser profile to separate them from your authenticated sessions on relevant websites.
- if you are worried about phishing, don't enter any personal information on the linked sites.